# WPF - how to hide menu item if command's CanExecute is false?

Tags: wpf, command, contextmenu, menuitem

By default menu items become disabled when its command cannot be executed (CanExecute = false). What is the easiest way to make the menu item visible/collapsed based on the CanExecute method?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can simply bind Visibility to IsEnabled (set to false on CanExecute == false).
You still would need an IValueConverter to convert the bool to visible/collapsed.

```
    public class BooleanToCollapsedVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //reverse conversion (false=>Visible, true=>collapsed) on any given parameter
            bool input = (null == parameter) ? (bool)value : !((bool)value);
            return (input) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: This is a bit more effort than necessary you can just use a trigger

Answer (score 60):

Thanks for the solution. For those wanting explicit XAML this might help:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<ContextMenu x:Key="innerResultsContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Open"
              Command="{x:Static local:Commands.AccountOpened}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" 
              CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
              Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
              />
</ContextMenu>
```

In my case, the context menu is a resource, so the binding for the visibility must use the RelativeSource Self binding setup.

As a side, for the CommandParameter, you might also pass the DataContext of the item whom was clicked to open the context menu. And in order to route the command bindings to the parent window, you will need to set the CommandTarget accordingly also.

Answer (score 50):

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

`CanExecute` toggles the `IsEnabled` property so just watch this and keep everything in the UI. Create a separate style if you want to reuse this.

Comment: This is perfect - worked like a charm (although I used a direct binding with a bool to visibility converter instead of a trigger, the idea is the same)

Comment: The visibility should be set to `Collapsed` as otherwise the hidden menu item will still occupy space.

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution although as per Roman's suggestion, visibility should be set to Collapsed

Comment: Changed visibility to 'Collapsed'.

Comment: changing the visibility is a change to style so using a style makes more sense than a direct binding

Comment: @MikeT I agree. It's easier to read and re-usable on several menu items or buttons without copy-paste.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft provides a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the easiest way, but you can always create a property which returns the `CanExecute()` and then bind the Visibility of your element to this property, using a `IValueConverter` to convert the boolean to Visibility.

Comment: This answer does not help much, but I'm giving it +1 to level those negative points that I completely do not understood why someone has given. While this answer is not too helpful, ALL things mentioned in it are VALID and moreover, all other positively-marked answers DO USE the things mentioned. The least pointvalue this answer deserves is zero, not negatives!

Comment: This was my initial thought, but how would you gain access to the (object param) parameter from within this new property, and pass it to CanExecute()?

Answer (score 1):

Binding Visibility to IsEnabled does the trick, but the required XAML is unpleasantly long and complicated:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

You can use an attached property to hide all the binding details and clearly convey your intent.

Here is the attached property:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class Bindings
    {
        public static bool GetVisibilityToEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(VisibilityToEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetVisibilityToEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(VisibilityToEnabledProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityToEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VisibilityToEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(Bindings), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnVisibilityToEnabledChanged));

        private static void OnVisibilityToEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (sender is FrameworkElement element)
            {
                if ((bool)args.NewValue)
                {
                    Binding b = new Binding
                    {
                        Source = element,
                        Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(FrameworkElement.IsEnabled)),
                        Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter()
                    };
                    element.SetBinding(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, b);
                }
                else
                {
                    BindingOperations.ClearBinding(element, UIElement.VisibilityProperty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you would use it:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.SomeClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">

    <ContextMenu x:Key="bazContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Open"
                  Command="{x:Static local:FooCommand}"
                  local:Bindings.VisibilityToEnabled="True"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window>
```